# Why is the temperature of a star not intensive?

Tags: thermodynamics, stars

The temperature of a star obviously depends on its mass. Does this mean that temperature is not always intensive?

Comment: Yes, and in this case that is because of the long-ranged nature of the gravitational force.

Comment: The pressure of the fluid in a hydraulic cylinder depends on how much force I put on the piston. That doesn't mean pressure isn't an intensive property of the fluid.

Comment: It means that equation of state dedicated for stars, ties temperature and mass of the object ( both as macroscopic property of such objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is that where there is more physics at work, the simple notion that two grams of water in thermal equilibrium have the same temperature as one gram no longer holds. In your example, this means that the temperature of a star after it thermonuclearly ignites will be greater than the same mass of hydrogen that has not ignited.

Comment: thermonuclear, eh? Then I guess they are not in equilibrium.